# I can't figure out where I'm leaking memory C++

Tags: c++, memory

```
Node::Node(void* value, Node* next)
{
    Value(value);
    Next(next);
}

Node::~Node()
{
    delete value;
    delete next;
}


Stack::Stack()
{
    top = 0;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty()){
        Node* node = top;
        delete top;
        top = node->Next();
    }
}
```

I'm sure the problem is with the push. Right now when I run it with this code it give me a access violation error.

```
void Stack::push(void* var)
{
    Node* node = new Node(var, top);
    top = node;
    delete node;
}

const void* Stack::pop()
{
    void* value = top->Value();
    top = top->Next();
    return value;
}

const void* Stack::peek() const
{
    if (top != 0)
    {
        return top->Value();
    }
    else
        return 0;
}

bool Stack::isEmpty() const
{
    return (top == 0);
}
```

I'm trying to create a stack in code using the heap for the data. I cant get rid of the memory leak. When I run this and push two ints. It tells me that I'm leaking 16 bits of data.

Comment: Things still teach void pointers instead of basic templates?

Comment: `top = node; delete node;` ... whereupon `top` becomes a dangling pointer.

Comment: `Node* node = top; delete top; top = node->Next();` is also broken - `node` points to the just-deleted object, so you can't dereference it to access `Next`. Perhaps `while (!isEmpty()) delete pop();`.  But - do note that deleteing a `void*` won't invoke any type-specific destructor, so it's not safe to do something like `myStack.push((void*)new std::string("hello!"));` - the `std::string` destructor will not be invoked when the stack's destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Stack::push(void* var)
{
    Node* node = new Node(var, top);
    top = node; // don't delete the created node, that is job of pop
                // otherwise u deleted the node u just pushed !!
}

const void* Stack::pop()
{
    void* value = 0;
    if (top)
    {
        value = top->Value();
        Node* nextTop = top->Next();
        delete top; // this would be correct!
        top = nextTop;
    }
    return value;
}

Stack::~Stack()
{
    while (!isEmpty())
       pop();
}
```

should do it!

But, why implement stack if you can use **STL**? why **raw** pointers? why **void*** use templates.

If you have C++, use most of its features, not just classes

Comment: Solid start - your code fixes `push` and `pop` - but FWIW `Stack::~Stack()` is also broken....

Comment: Its a project in school and im required to use a void*

Comment: I had to get rid of whats inside of my node deconstructor to get this to work with that being said I LOVE YOU I WAS STUCK ON THIS FOR HOURS THANK YOU SO MUCH.